# How to load NTU rgbd dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning

We are working on early action prediction but we are unable to understand the dataset itself NTU rgbd dataset is 1.3 tb.my laptop Hard disk is 931 GB
 .first problem : how to deal with such a big dataset?
Second problem : how to understand dataset?
Third problem: how to load dataset ?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The overall size of the dataset is 1.3 TB and this size will decrease after processing the data and converting it into numpy arrays or something else.
But I do not think you will work on the entire dataset, what is the part you want to work on it in the dataset?

Comment: Can you answer the specific problems? If you have more questions, ask them as comments and then come up with a complete answer.

Comment: "you must have 50 reputation to comment"